# CMake "undefined reference to function"

Tags: c++, c, cmake, clion

I am attempting to use CMake to link a library([BNO055 Driver](https://github.com/BoschSensortec/BNO055_driver)). Since the BNO055 Driver doesn't use CMake and it hasn't been changed for about a year I decided to just download the source files and put them in my project.

I then use CMake to create a library and link it.

The issue is that the link does not seem to be working. When I compile the project I get a `undefined reference to <function>` error, where `<function>` is a function defined by the BNO055 driver.

Am I creating or linking the library incorrectly?
Do I need to do something else to define these functions?

For the sake of not pasting in 200 lines of code, here is a simplified `main.cpp` that produces the same error as the real `main.cpp`. If you would like to see the real `main.cpp` follow the link bellow to the Github repo

```
#include "bno055.h"
#include "mraa.hpp"

struct bno055_t bno055;
mraa::I2c *i2c(0);

int main() {
    bno055_init(&bno055);
    i2c->address(0x29);
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(imc-server)

# CMake
# -- Config
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")

# Global
# -- Include
include(ExternalProject)

# BNO055
# -- Include
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bno055)

set(SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES}
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bno055/bno055.h
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bno055/bno055.c)

# MRAA
# -- Build
externalProject_add(mraa
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa.git
        GIT_TAG        v0.7.5
)

# Compile
# -- Source
set(SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES}
        main.cpp)

# -- Create
add_executable(imc-server ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_dependencies(imc-server mraa)
```

**Relevant Part of Build Log**

```
[ 90%] Linking CXX executable imc-server
CMakeFiles/imc-server.dir/test.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/noah/Documents/Inertial-Motion-Capture/imc-server/test.cpp:8: undefined reference to `bno055_init(bno055_t*)'
CMakeFiles/imc-server.dir/test.cpp.o: In function `mraa::I2c::address(unsigned char)':
/usr/local/include/mraa/i2c.hpp:99: undefined reference to `mraa_i2c_address'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [imc-server] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/imc-server.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

[Project Github](https://github.com/Noah-Huppert/Inertial-Motion-Capture/tree/39a6196e48623c76323b92d37bf6e811c22f3ad5/imc-server)(`39a6196`)
[Build Log](http://pastebin.com/Av5p45eK)

Comment: You use `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bno055/bno055.c` file for build `bno055` library, so you shouldn't use that file for build `imc-server` executable. Also, it is better to use library target name for link that executable: `target_link_libraries(imc-server bno055)`. As for external project `mraa`, you additionally need explicit target dependencies for correctly link with it: `add_dependencies(imc-server mraa)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok, I just added the BNO055 files to the executable(So no lib or linking for bno055). However I am still getting undefined function errors. I also uncommented all the mraa code and I am getting undefined function errors for those functions as well. Is there something I am fundamentally missing here? [Commit with changes => 39a6196](https://github.com/Noah-Huppert/Inertial-Motion-Capture/tree/39a6196e48623c76323b92d37bf6e811c22f3ad5/imc-server)

Comment: Which source is being compiled, when you get error? Precise error message(at least, for one function) would be helpful.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Indeed, Here is the end part of the CMake build log. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Av5p45eK)

Comment: As build log shows, function (`mraa_i2c_address`) is defined in the `mraa` library, not in the `bno055` one. You need both link with that library (`target_link_libraries(imc-server libmraa.so`) and add dependency with `mraa` target (`add_dependencies(imc-server mraa)`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Awesome! Now only the BNO055 functions are missing. Even though I include them in the executable build

Comment: @Tsyvarev The Undefined BNO055 errors where from an other issue. If you want, put your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was that the BNO055 library was written in C, and my program was written in C++.

I learned that to use a function defined in a C program, in a C++ program, you have to wrap the include of the C library in an `extern "C" {}` block like so:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "bno055.h"
}
#include "mraa.hpp"

struct bno055_t bno055;
mraa::I2c *i2c(0);

int main() {
    bno055_init(&bno055);
    i2c->address(0x29);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the header from your SOURCE_FILES.

```
set(SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES}
        # ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bno055/bno055.h
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bno055/bno055.c)
```

CMake should find the required header by itself. Additional includes are found by `include_directories`

Comment: The issue was that I had to wrap the bno055 include in a `extern "C" {}"`

Comment: maybe you could post your own answer, it would be more visible